# Busca sem refresh por select

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Boa noite... gostaria de saber como faço uma busca atraves de um **select** e de **checkbox**, como no site do webmotors...

Procurei na internet mas não achei nada parecido... Alguem conhece algo assim?

Comment: Sem refresh é usando `Jquery.Ajax()`

Comment: Tem alguma coisa no git com isso... pq nao sei nem da onde comecar

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ a documentação

Comment: Como foi dito, tem que ser usando AJAX.Ai tu coloca um evento onchange no select ou checkbox que vai chamar a sua função AJAX ai tu coloca o resultado em uma div.